# How to divide a string into several strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, split

First, I'll explain, what I want to archive: assuming the following string,    `25a0:   ebfffa01    bl  dac <abort@plt>` (notice there are whitespaces before the first character), then my target is to get the following output:

```
25a0:
ebfffa01
bl
dac
<abort@plt>
```

The problem is that the string can be divided by several (consecutive) whitespaces, therefore my current solution does not work correctly:

```
vector<vector<string>> getStructuredContent(vector<string> content) {
    vector<vector<string>> structuredContent;
    for(string line: content) {
        char space_char = ' ';
        vector<string> words{};
        stringstream sstream(line);
        string word;
        while (getline(sstream, word, space_char)){
            if(word != "")
            words.push_back(word);
        }
        structuredContent.push_back(words);
    }
    return structuredContent;
}
```

The output for the string above is currently:

```
25a0:   ebfffa01
        bl      dac
<abort@plt>
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you use a [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) or a [grammar](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html)?

Comment: never used a regex or grammar before. You maybe have an example for that?

Comment: You have the right idea in looking for space delimited strings and storing them, although I don't know why you are using a `vector<vector<string>>` instead of a simple `vector<string>`. That's part of your issue. The second is you aren't handling consecutive spaces correctly. I'd scratch what you have and start over. Build a word one character at a time until you hit a space, then push that word into your `vector<string>`. Then continue until you hit a non-space character and repeat.

Comment: Formatted input `>>` discards whitespace, so `while (sstream >> word) words.push_back(word);` seems like it would do what you want.

Comment: the solution by using >> works fine. Thank you very much!